# How to prevent automatic hibernation while watching videos?

Tags: 14.04, hibernate, system

I have my settings to hibernate after 20 minutes and after 5 minutes it kicks into hibernate even when I'm watching a movie. I'm a complete newbie with Linux. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and my computer is a HP 655 laptop also I have xscreensavor.

Comment: Are you using the Unity desktop or Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Gnome Shell, or Lubuntu?

Comment: unity i think sorry im a noob

Answer (score 5):

You can use Caffeine.

> "Caffeine is designed to help your computer stay awake. It’s chiefly used to prevent a screensaver or lock-screen from kicking in when you don’t want it to (e.g., watching videos or leaving music playing in the background while you snooze)." [(more info)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine)

---

Caffeine is available in the default repositories since 16.04 and no PPA is required anymore. To install it, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and then enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install caffeine
```

Type your password when prompted for a password by `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings again go to:

**system settings**

[image]

**brightness & lock**

[image]

make sure **dim screen brightness to save power** is **not** selected

make sure **turn screen off when inactive for:** is set to **never**

if the problem persists, consider filing a bug report

make sure **lock** is **off**

and make sure **require my password when waking from suspend** is **not** selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the pc awake based on network traffic, or cpu load or user activity then you can try Keep.Awake instead of Caffeine https://launchpad.net/keep.awake

I haven't developed a GUI for it yet so you will need to use the command prompt.

I still haven't gotten around to creating a snap or deb for it. However temporarily you can download the program from Launchpad [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ferncasado/keep.awake/trunk/files/head:/v4/)

The current version is stable and works on all Ubuntu versions from 14.04 up to 16.04. That said I am continually improving it and will be adding new features.

It works like a proper command. Type --help to see a full listing of what can be done. The examples underneath are only a few:

```
./keepawake.py --help
```

To run interactively:

```
./keepawake.py
```

To run as a background service:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set 15 min (900 sec) as the user activity idle time before it determines that the user is idle:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -u 900 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set minimum CPU load as 13%:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -c 13 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run as background service and set minimum network traffic as 5KB (5120 bytes):

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -s 5120 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To run all three settings above (network, CPU, User idle) in the one go:

```
nohup ./keepawake.py -s 5120 -c 13 -u 900 -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hi @DanglingPointer. You've posted the same answer four times. It'd be much more helpful if you mark the questions as duplicates in the future. That way, you only have to post your answer once and it makes the solution easier to find for everyone. Also, please clear up your affiliation with the project you've linked to (if you are indeed the author). Users who promote their own stuff in a lot of places run the risk of getting flagged for spam!

Comment: Regarding the duplicates, sure no problem.
As for being the author, well it is quite obvious if you read it that I wrote it.
If someone is asking for a solution to a problem for which I have a free and open source solution that addresses it;  what's the problem there?  It's just a command.  The whole purpose of this site is to find answers and solutions.  There's nothing being sold here.