# Automatic suspend notification

Tags: suspend, notification

Often while watching movies I get "automatic suspend" notification in 15 minutes even though here it says one hour.[image: pic1].

I want to turn off the notification on Ubuntu 23.10. While looking for solutions online, I was suggested to install gnome-tweaks, but it doesn't have an option to turn off the notification.
[image: pic2]

Any other suggestions? This is very annoying, as I have to move the mouse every 15 minutes if I watch a movie.

Comment: Does installing caffeine work?

Comment: @DanielT it actually worked, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent automatic hibernation while watching videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508322/how-to-prevent-automatic-hibernation-while-watching-videos)

Comment: @DanielT it helped me in practice, but I was wondering on how to turn off the notifications instead of preventing the hibernation altogether.

Comment: Can't you disable this notification in settings or turn on Do Not Disturb?

Comment: @DanielT I may turn off the power notifications. But then I will not know if the battery is down.

Comment: @DanielT UPD: Caffeine doesn't block the hibernation notifications as I falsely claimed above.